React got infinite loop when use useState() hook in layout file
Got a project in react-native + expo + react-native-web, I need to show username or login link via the layout file depending on whether username is stored in the storage.
app/_layout.tsx:
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Link, Slot} from "expo-router";
import Constants from "expo-constants/src/Constants";
import storageUtil from "@/utils/storage";
import constStorage from "@/constants/Storage";

export default () => {
  // username from storage, indicate whether already login,
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string | null>(null);
  storageUtil.getItem(constStorage.keys.username).then(v => {
    console.log('username from storage: ', v)
    if (username !== v)  // add to avoid infinite loop, TODO: improve.
      setUsername(v)
  })

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View id='header' style={{flex: 1}}><Text>
        {username ?
          (<Link href="/home">{username}</Link>)
          : (<Link href="/login">Login</Link>)
        }
      </Text></View>
      <View id='main' style={{flex: 2, width: '100%', minHeight: 350, padding: 8}}>
        <Slot/>
      </View>
      <View id='footer' style={{flex: 3}}><Text>Footer</Text></View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight, // don't go to statusbar of phone,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    position: 'relative',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})

If I remove the line if (username !== v), in browser, when I click the username or Login link, it triggers infinite loop. 
aka. console.log('username from storage: ', v) I can see this log line in chrome console printed infinitely quickly, and cpu is high.
So, how to avoid this infinite loop, other than the if (username !== v) I added, which is not elegant I think.

Calling storageUtil.getItem causes setting username with setUsername, that causes component re-rendering, that causes calling storageUtil.getItem, and again and again.
To prevent this you need to use one-time useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  storageUtil.getItem(constStorage.keys.username).then(v => {
    setUsername(v);
  })
}, []);


It seems I'd better use useEffect() without the , [] param, otherwise after login success the username is not displayed, instead it still show login link, which means the content inside useEffect() is not executed when go from /login to /home via router.replace('/home');.
